Native iOS app: How to make images the exact same physical size on all devices - Iphone to Ipad
I use 2x assets for Ipad as supposed to.
But the physical size is a bit bigger on Ipad(Ipad 2 Pro) than on Iphone(Iphone 16 Pro). I have debugged and verified that the exact same assets are used across my Iphone and my Ipad.
Also, I have no constraints set differently between Ipad and Iphone.
Is there any way of making it the exact same size across all supported devices?
I have found no solution to this via Apples documentation or in any other posts.
I assume most devs do not have this need, but for an app measuring visual acuity it is a must.

Please update your question with far more relevant details. Are you talking about a web page? A native iOS app? Add relevant tags. Add details about your current implementation and show the results you are getting and clearly explain what results you want to get instead.
